# Javascript performance problems

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling

Can someone please help me figure out what the heck JavaScript is doing behind the scenes that's taking so much time? In a program I'm writing I have a simple loop like so:

```
function loop () {  
    update_cells();
    grid.draw();
    draw_cells();
}

(function setup() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    grid = new Grid(settings.gridSize);
    cells = new _2DArray(grid.size);
    randomize2DArray(cells);

    function animloop()
    {
        loop();
        requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
    }

    animloop();
}());
```

I've been timing the program and have determined that whatever JavaScript is doing between each iteration of the loop is taking up about 95% of the running time of the program. A profiling timeline just shows (program) running practically forever in between each loop iteration. Any ideas what this might be? Here's a link to the full program in case you want to take a look at it: http://cdpn.io/ajflL

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: So I literally just added ctx.beginPath() somewhere I'd forgotten it and the perforance improved 1000 fold. Had no idea that little line of code was so important.